# Pushing array to Firebase via REST API

Tags: api, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

## Question

> How do I (with a **single HTTP request** to the **REST API**) write an **array** to Firebase and give each array element a (non-integer) **unique ID**?

[As described here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push).

---

### Data

The data I have to write looks like the following.

data-to-write.js

```
myArray = [ {"user_id": "jack", "text": "Ahoy!"},
            {"user_id": "jill", "text": "Ohai!"} ];
```

### Goal

When finished, I want my Firebase to look like this following.

my-firebase.firebaseio.com

```
{
  "posts": {
    "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": { // <- unique ID (non-integer)
      "user_id": "jack",
      "text": "Ahoy!"
    },
    "-JRHTHaKuITFIhnj02kE": { // <- unique ID (non-integer)
      "user_id": "jill",
      "text": "Ohai!"
    }
  }
}
```

I **do not** want it to look like this following...

my-anti-firebase.firebaseio.com

```
// NOT RECOMMENDED - use push() instead!
{
  "posts": {
    "0": {  // <- ordered array index (integer)
      "user_id": "jack",
      "text": "Ahoy!"
    },
    "1": {  // <- ordered array index (integer)
      "user_id": "jill",
      "text": "Ohai!"
    }
  }
}
```

[I note this page where it says](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html):

> [...] if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values, then Firebase will render it as an array.

### Code

Because I want to do this in a single HTTP request, I want to avoid iterating over each element in the array and, instead, I want to push a batch in a single request.

In other words, I want to do something like this:

pseudocode.js

```
curl -X POST -d '[{"user_id": "jack", "text": "Ahoy!"},
                  {"user_id": "jill", "text": "Ohai!"}]' \
                  // I want some type of batch operation here
  'https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/posts.json'
```

However, when I do this, I get exactly what I describe above that I don't want (i.e., sequential integer keys).

I want to avoid doing something like this:

anti-pseudocode.js

```
for(i=0; i<=myArray.length; i++;){ // I want to avoid iterating over myArray
  curl -X POST -d '{"user_id": myArray[i]["user_id"],
                    "text": myArray[i]["text"]}' \
    'https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/posts.json'
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish what I have described? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to use the Firebase API to do this as described in the OP.

However, it can be done with a server script as follows:

1. Iterate through each array element.
2. Assign each element a unique id (generated by server script).
3. Create a return object with keys being the unique IDs and values being the corresponding array elements.
4. Write object to Firebase with a single HTTP request using the `patch` method. Because `post` creates a new Firebase generated ID for the entire object itself. Whereas, `patch` does not; it writes directly to the parent node.

script.js

```
var myObject = {},
i = myArray.length;
while(i--){
  var key = function(){ /* return unique ID */ }();
  myObject[key] = myArray[i];
}
curl -X PATCH -d JSON.stringify(myObject) \
'https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/posts.json'
```

Comment: I found this https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11 function to generate firebase-pushId-like unique Ids

Answer (score 1):

Your decision to use POST is correct. The one which cause numeric indexes as a key is because your payload is an array. Whenever you post/put and array, the key will always be indexes. Post your object one by one if you want the server generate key for you.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase will generate unique ID only if you use `POST`. If you use `PATCH` unique ID is not generated.

Hence for the given case, will need to iterate through using some server/ client side code to save data in firebase.

**Peseudo Code:**

```
For each array 
   curl -X POST -d 
       "user_id": "jack",
       "text": "Ahoy!" 
    'https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/posts.json'
Next
```